# Count total rows of all tables in a database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rowcount

I would like to count the total rows of all tables of a SQL Server database, does anyone knows how can I do that query?

I will use this information in a job to transfer information between layers of a data lake.

Comment: What is its use case?

Comment: I will use this information to provision some resources in the data lake processes between layers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a glance to the following article;

[Different approaches of counting number of rows in a table](https://basitaalishan.com/tag/sys-partitions/)

This is my favorite one;

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) AS [table_schema]
          ,OBJECT_NAME(p.[object_id]) AS [table_name]
          ,SUM(p.[rows]) AS [row_count]
    FROM [sys].[partitions] p
    INNER JOIN [sys].[tables] t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
    WHERE p.[index_id] < 2
    GROUP BY p.[object_id]
        ,t.[schema_id]
    ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

[image]

This one find out total number of the SQL Database

```
SELECT 
      SUM(p.[rows]) AS [row_count]
FROM [sys].[partitions] p
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables] t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE p.[index_id] < 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Used the following query to count all the rows of all tables of a database.

```
SELECT SUM(i.rowcnt)
FROM sysindexes AS i
INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id = o.id
WHERE i.indid < 2
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
```

Comment: This is not a blogging platform. And a trivial amount of searching would have found this exact approach.

Comment: @SMor that's why I thought that an easy answer could help a lot of people, but thanks for help me improve my answers.